# Htaccess not working in godaddy server

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am facing an issue while redirecting a url using `.htaccess`.

When I try to open the page I get an a 404 error page.

Here is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Force www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.      
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysitename.com/myproject/$1 [R=301,L]   

Options -Indexes

RewriteRule ^newname/([0-9]+)$ index.php?stid=$1
```

Comment: What's the actual problem you are having?

Comment: You may want to ask this over at webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to point the URL it's rewriting to to the base on the root of the site.

```
RewriteRule ^newname/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?stid=$1
```